# Android project migration from Windows to Mac (IClasspathEntry must be absolute)

Tags: android, eclipse, classpath

I've sorted out most problems with migrating an old Android project from Windows to Mac, but a path issue remains.

When I load up Eclipse, it gives me an error message saying:

"Parsing Data for android-7 failed.  Source attachment path 'C:\Android\sdk\sources\android-17' for iClasspathEntry must be absolute"

Obviously this path is wrong, but where on earth do I change it?

Comment: Try to go into Projects -> Properties -> Java Build Path. On the Libraries page expand the library's node and see if you are getting an error there? You might need to change the path there.

Comment: There are no incorrect paths in the Java Build Settings.  

In the Libraries section, there was previously a bad path to android.jar.  I couldn't figure out how to add it like it was before (previously it had a Library icon next to it and a drop down and contained within that was android.jar, but when I tried to add it, android.jar would be on the first level) so I deleted it in all projects, and then did "Fix project properties" which fixed all projects except the main one.  When I do "Fix project properties" on this one, it gives me the aforementioned error.

Comment: I had a similar error doing the same thing with a grails project, I found the source entries in a file under the .settings directory of the project so might be worth looking there

Answer (score 9):

I was facing the same issue and found and found [a useful link](http://www.mikesel.info/show-hidden-files-mac-os-x-10-7-lion/) to show hidden files on a mac.

Run the following command from the terminal window on mac

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

After that, relaunch finder (alt+ right click)

Then it will show the hidden file .metadata folder.

Delete the following file:

```
.metedata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web/webLibrariesCache.index
```

Restarted eclipse; the error should go away.

Comment: For those who are new with mac (sorry if the question may seem stupid but) where is located the .metadata folder? I ran the command but still do not see it...

Answer (score 3):

First close Eclipse.

Then go to

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.root/.indexes
```

Open the file with a text editor and change the path for the SDK.

Restart Eclipse and everything should be fine!